# $\infty$-groupoid iff Kan condition

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

I'm going through Chapter 4 of "Homotopy Theory and Arithmetic Geometry - Motivic and Diophantine Aspects" which begins with an overview of $\infty$-categories. Theorem 2 states that a simplicial set $C\in Set^{\Delta^{op}}$ is an $\infty$-groupoid iff for every horn inclusion $\Lambda^n_i\hookrightarrow\Delta^n$ with $0\leq i\leq n$ we have a dashed arrow that gives us the following commutative diagram

[image]

I am a bit confused as to why this is true. Although a reference or explanation of a formal proof would be nice, I'm more so interested in getting an intuitive understanding of this fact. In particular I'm wondering, why do the outer horns give us isomorphisms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to start is the following characterization of nerves of ordinary groupoids:

> A category is a groupoid if and only if its nerve is a Kan complex.

Filling the outer horns is precisely what constructs inverses of morphisms.

See, for example, [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/0035).

Comment: Took a look, thought for a little, and now I understand what's going on. Thanks.